# Retrieve value from javascript funcion on client click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, vs-web-site-project

I have a function on JS that must execute before the codebehind, but i'm having trouble retrieving it.
It will return a variable that i should use on the codebehind. The function i created is this one:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" >
                function returnHash() {
                    var checkout = new DirectCheckout('086F7D02A071267FEBF102EB759D9845B8B3333DFA65BC45B807F41A8525AD8D'); /* Em sandbox utilizar o construtor new DirectCheckout('SEU TOKEN PUBLICO', false); */
                    debugger;
                    var month = document.getElementById("txtDataVencUser").value;
                    var year = document.getElementById("txtDataVencUser").value;

                    var cardData = {
                        cardNumber: document.getElementById("txtNumeroCartaoUser").value,
                        holderName: document.getElementById("txtNomeCartaoUser").value,
                        securityCode: document.getElementById("txtCodSegurancaUser").value,
                        expirationMonth: month.substring(0, 2),
                        expirationYear: "20" + year.substring(3, 5)
                    };

                    checkout.getCardHash(cardData, function (cardHash) {
----------------------------> I NEED TO RETRIEVE "cardHash" VALUE IN CODEBEHIND
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
                </script>
```

I don't know if this step is correct, but i am using the onClientClick to try to execute the JS before the codebehind:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFinalizarCompraJunoUser" runat="server" Text="FINALIZAR COMPRA" OnClientClick="returnHash()" OnClick="btnFinalizarCompraJunoUser_Click" Visible="true" />
```

I am having trouble figuring out what to do next, can someone help me please?

Comment: A common thing to do is to set a hidden form field value so it posts with the form to the server.

Comment: It looks like `getCardHash` has a promise-like signature where you can confirm a "success" and a "failed" callback. If this is the case, then you're probably facing the problem where this function finishes before waiting for the "success"-callback. I don't know if `OnClientClick` supports `async`-functions, but if it does, you could try rewriting the function to use `await`.

Comment: @Stanislas, i am quite new to javascript, where should i declare the await operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways - perhaps as many flavors of ice cream.

But, since you are going to run a "code behind" stub based on the click?

I would just drop a hidden field on the page, and then just set that value in js

So right below your button - add a hidden field say like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick="myfun();return true" Width="68px"
        ClientIDMode="Static"/>

     <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myfun() {
    // do whatever - walk the dog - have fun!!!

    var f1 = document.getElementById("HiddenField1");
    f1.value = "2222";
}
</script>
```

So in above I just shove 2222 into the hidden1 field.

Now, in the the code behind button stub, you can do this:

```
 Debug.Print("my click f1 = " & HiddenField1.Value);
```

So the code behind will now have a good old regular plane jane control to look at and get the value in question.

So, it depends on how many values - but using a code behind friendly (asp.net) control and setting the value with the js client side code probably is the least effort here.

I also of course used "staticID" for the above. If you for some reason don't like (or want) to use staticID for above, then the js selection would be:

```
 var f1 = document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.Clientid%>");
 f1.value = cardHash;
```

Comment: for some reason, if i trigger your answer BEFORE actually doing onclickclient in the button, it works!

but if i use it within onClientClick, the hidden field always returns empty, any idea?

Comment: is the js code async? in this case that would be the call to routine getCardHash? If that bit of code is written as asynchronous then when you call it, it does NOT wait and your button event code will thus trigger.  you can try/see if this is the case by using a console.log(cardhash) in the js code.  This is much the say as say using a jQuery dialog in place of say alert() or confirm(). alert()/confirm() halts the js code, you make a choice and the code continues (so you can use say alert/confirm to return true or false in a OnClientClick() event.

Comment: You can't use say a jQuery.UI dialog to return true or false based on user hitting "ok" or "cancel" because the jQuery (and most library widgets including bootstrap dialogs) do NOT halt code. So you can't pop that dialog, wait for response and then have code continue. You can ONLY pop the dialog, and based on say user hitting ok button or cancel button can THEN run + launch another small routine in your code when ok it hit, or another small js routine when cancel is hit - but the code its self thus does not wait. You thus of course can't set some var like cardHash if the call does not wait.

Comment: So right after you get/call  cardHash do a console.log and see what the browser spits out in the browser debugger (f12).  this will give you and tell you this answer in 30 seconds of your effort and time. If yes (async), then you get rid of the onClientClick event. Drop in new buttion and call getCardHas and THEN you grab that existing button into a js var, and then do a var.click() to trigger that original button. Just like a jQuery dialog you split this into two routines because the call to the dialog (or in your case that getCard routine) does NOT wait - the code may be asynchronous.